# Looking for a good web penetration testing client

Tags: apache-2.2, http, mod-security, security

I'm implementing `mod_security` on an apache server. In order to test the effectiveness of the protection, I am looking for a client that can generate a set of predefined malicious HTTP requests. I will test the requests with and without `mod_security` enabled and based on the logs see what percentage of malicious requests has been blocked.

Do you know any good tools to generate a set of predefined malicious HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several free/open source options out there.  A close friend of mine who's a Web applications pen tester uses none of these (with exception to Nessus, but only the Professional Feed) as their toolset is quite a bit more sophisticated and contains many unpublished zero day exploits.  However, they're very expensive and require certain certifications/qualifications to purchase.

While these tools may not be on the bleeding edge as far as pure, zero-day vulnerability scanning goes, there's still alot of older, well-known vulnerabilities that are exploited daily, so this will certainly give you a pretty good idea of what's potentially vulnerable on your system, exploit or not (i.e. finding unscrubbed parameters, any misconfigurations, etc.).

- [Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus) (the Professional Feed is > $1000/yr, but the free version still has quite a few vulnerabilities)
- [Metasploit Framework](http://www.metasploit.com/)
- [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/)
- [Nikto2](http://cirt.net/nikto2)
- [SkipFish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/)

Couple of things that you may not be aware:

- Full scans can take *days* sometimes *weeks* to complete, depending on the size of the site, the network (see below), and the breadth/depth of scan rules  Plan accordingly.
- Some of the scanners have throttling features but because of the sheer volume of requests, it's better to:

  a) test your Web application on a fast network (LAN);

  b) obviously this Web application shouldn't be in production and if so, I'd be running it with a test data set;

  c) have plenty of resources for logging (or disable it altogether).

You may also want to periodically check the [online vulnerability databases](http://www.exploit-db.com/) for known exploits out there; I do a periodic search for any open source Web applications I'm hosting and disable or patch as required (I'm looking at you [Joomla](http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_description=joomla&filter_exploit_text=&filter_author=&filter_platform=0&filter_type=0&filter_lang_id=0&filter_port=&filter_osvdb=&filter_cve=)).